# "broke his arm" vs. "his arm broke"

Tags: phrase-choice, transitivity

What is the correct sentence?

1. He fell and broke his arm.
2. He fell and his arm broke.

Answer (score 1):

Both are possible, however the transitive verb form, e.g. cut his finger, broke his arm, twisted his ankle, is much more common.

Answer (score 0):

Both of them are proper, however I would prefer:

> He fell and broke his arm.

(not really any reason)

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are grammatical. However, "his arm broke" in this context would imply that it happened spontaneously and without any action on his part - like if you were walking down the street, heard a crack, looked down and saw your arm dangling at a weird angle.

Since arms don't tend to spontaneously explode, it's a rather rare usage.